# How to transform a list into a list of pairs like that?

Tags: scala, collections

Suppose I have a list of `A`:

```
case class A(x: Int, y: Int)
val as = List(A(0, 0), A(0, 1), A(1, 0), A(1, 1))
```

I would like to transform it into a list of pairs `(A, Set[A])` so that:

- list of the fist elements of pairs is `as`
- in each pair `(a, set)` `set` consists of such items of `as` that have the same `x` or `y` as `a`

For example:

```
val pairs = List(
  A(0, 0) -> Set(A(0, 1), A(1, 0)),
  A(0, 1) -> Set(A(0, 0), A(1, 1)),
  A(1, 0) -> Set(A(0, 0), A(1, 1)),
  A(1, 1) -> Set(A(0, 1), A(1, 0))
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Brute force":

```
case class A(x: Int, y: Int)
val as = List(A(0, 0), A(0, 1), A(1, 0), A(1, 1))

val mappings = for {
  a1 <- as
  a2 <- as
  if (a1 != a2)
  if (a1.x == a2.x || a1.y == a2.y)
} yield a1 -> a2

val result = mappings.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

Comment: It's good enough for small lists, thank you. I am just wondering whether it's possible to do it more efficiently than `O(N^2)`

Comment: Hardly, I think. Although you could avoid some of grouping and mapping at the end with a mutable map.

Comment: I strongly prefer immutable collections. Thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Comment: Oh, now I see it. We have to check _all_ pairs, So the algorithm should be `O(N^2)`

Answer (score 1):

With some indexing you might get something a bit faster on the average case (while paying some extra storage for the indices):

First we create an index for Xs and Ys:

```
val xi = as.groupBy(_.x) // O(n) 
val yi = as.groupBy(_.y) // O(n)
```

Then we do a single pass and map each element using the indices:

```
// This is essentially O(n^2) worst case, but it can be much less if the toSet doesn't have to go through a lot each time
val inter = for( a <- as ) yield 
   (a, (xi.get(a.x).toSet ++ yi.get(a.y).toSet).flatten)
```

Finally, you might want to remove from the Set the same elements as the key:

```
inter.map(x => (x._1, x._2 - x._1)) // O(n)
```

So overall this is still worst case O(n^2), but in the cases where the indices are sparse enough, it can be essentially O(n).